# How to displays multiple file using flask

Tags: python, flask

im newbie in python,  I have a folder with a list of file .tar. I have to display them in my demo application with flask as below, My app.py

```py
@app.route("/")
def index():  
    os.listdir(data_file_dir)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

how to display the contents of the directory directory `data_file_dir` in html? using flask?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List files in directories with flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828538/list-files-in-directories-with-flask), also see [How to generate an html directory list using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961991/)

Answer (score 1):

```
@app.route("/")
def index():  
    return render_template('index.html', dir = os.listdir(data_file_dir))
```

and in your html code use jinja 2:
place this code where ever you want to display that list of dir

```
{{dir}}
```