# How to list files of a directory with flask (using bootstraps) and python?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, bootstrapping

This is my first Question I make on this forum. I am so desperate to find a solution... Hope I can learn from you guys.
I had a solution, but with posting the whole directorytree in the browserwindow and knowing the filename, which is not like I want it.

Now I found such code snippet and changed it a little bit. Its generator expression, which is I think not supported with Jinja2:

```
import os
path = r"C:/Users/add706/Documents/NRL_webseite/website/static/uploads"

def get_files(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)):
            yield file  
for file in get_files(path):
    print(file)
```

The output gives me 3 files inside the path:
1.jpeg
postgre.jpeg
winrar-x64-610d.exe

I am trying to make a list and pass it to JINJA2. I have created already a template, but somehow, when I run flask, I cant list the files and the print function is empty. Since 3 days I am sitting on it and there is not even an error message, which could help me.

This is my original outtake of auth.py (imports of libraries are fine, not listed here):

```
path = r"C:/Users/add706/Documents/NRL_webseite/website/static/uploads"

@auth.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])  
def get_files(path):
    
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)):
            return (os.listdir(path))
    files=[]
    for file in get_files(path):
        files.append(file)
        print(files)      
        return render_template('home.html', files=get_files(path))
```

This is my original outtake of home.html template (which was %extended%), looping through the returned files ( I wish to...):

```
<!-- download Folder-->
<div align="center">
<image src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/postgre.jpeg')}}">

</ul>
        {% for file in files %}
    <li class="collection-item"><a href="#">{{ file }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The question is now: What do I have to change in my both files that I can see the 3 files on my local webpage (http://127.0.0.1:5000/)? I would like to list them and make them clickable, so while clicking, the file can be downloaded as attachment. Second thing is, to list them with upload time. THird thing is, that the download process, let a window popping up, which asks me "DO you wish to download (filename). To visualize my problem, I uploaded an image and drew red boxes. Thanks in regard for every help out there.

Image link: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFKrP.jpg)

I have found this article, which says in my script that tree is undefined ([List files in directories with flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828538/list-files-in-directories-with-flask)), so I gave it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use a generator inside jinja2.
The example I wrote should meet your needs.
It displays the files within the directory as a list. Each entry is assigned its size and the time of upload. The uploads folder is inside the [instance folder](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#instance-folders) to separate the files from the application.
I use [flask-moment](https://flask-moment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to show the correct times. This uses [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) and displays the timestamp in the respective time zone of the client.
I use a custom Jinja2 [filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#custom-filters) to display the file size.
If a file is clicked to download, a dialog opens that requests confirmation. This is done using JavaScript.
Have fun achieving your goals.

###### Flask (app.py)

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    send_from_directory
)
from flask_moment import Moment
from datetime import datetime
import os

def byte_units(value, units=-1):
    UNITS=('Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB')
    i=1
    value /= 1000.0
    while value > 1000 and (units == -1 or i < units) and i+1 < len(UNITS):
        value /= 1000.0
        i += 1
    return f'{round(value,3):.3f} {UNITS[i]}'


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads')
app.jinja_env.filters.update(byte_units = byte_units)
moment = Moment(app)

try:
    os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
except:
    pass

def get_files(target):
    for file in os.listdir(target):
        path = os.path.join(target, file)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            yield (
                file,
                datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path)),
                os.path.getsize(path)
            )

@app.route('/')
def index():
    files = get_files(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
        filename,
        as_attachment=True
    )
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <table style="width:40%; margin:auto; table-layout: fixed;">
      {% for filename, mtime, size in files -%}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=filename) }}" download>{{ filename }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ moment(mtime, local=False).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm') }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">{{ size | byte_units }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor -%}
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (() => {
        const elems = document.querySelectorAll('a[href][download]');
        elems.forEach(elem => {
          elem.addEventListener('click', evt => {
            const isDonwload = window.confirm('Would you like to download this file?');
            if (!isDonwload) { evt.preventDefault(); }
          });
        });
      })();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

I've added my code to your project. It should work now.

You should work on structuring your project so that you can find your way around the code more easily. I cannot relieve you of this task in this context.

###### (website/**init**.py)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

DB_NAME = "database.db"

db = SQLAlchemy()
moment = Moment()

def byte_units(value, units=-1):
    UNITS=('Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB')
    i=1
    value /= 1000.0
    while value > 1000 and (units == -1 or i < units) and i+1 < len(UNITS):
        value /= 1000.0
        i += 1
    return f'{round(value,3):.3f} {UNITS[i]}'

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY=b'your secret here',
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///'+os.path.join(app.instance_path, DB_NAME),
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,
        UPLOAD_FOLDER=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads')
    )
    app.jinja_env.filters.update(byte_units = byte_units)

    try:
        os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    except:
        pass

    db.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)

    from .models import User, Note

    create_database(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')

    return app


def create_database(app):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(app.instance_path, DB_NAME)):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Created Database!')
```

###### (website/auth.py)

```
import os
import json
from . import db
from .models import User
from flask import (
    Blueprint,
    flash,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    url_for
)
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                flash('Logged in successfully!', category='success')
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect password, try again.', category='error')
        else:
            flash('Email does not exist.', category='error')

    return render_template('login.html', user=current_user)

@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        first_name = request.form.get('firstName')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            flash('Email already exists.', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email must be greater than 3 characters.', category='error')
        elif len(first_name) < 2:
            flash('First name must be greater than 1 character.', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords don\'t match.', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 7:
            flash('Password must be at least 7 characters.', category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(
                password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(new_user, remember=True)
            flash('Account created!', category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template('sign_up.html', user=current_user)
```

###### (website/views.py)

```
from . import db
from .models import Note
from flask import Blueprint, current_app, flash, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from datetime import datetime
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note = request.form.get('note')

        if len(note) < 1:
            flash('Note is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            new_note = Note(data=note, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_note)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Note added!', category='success')

    user=current_user
    files = get_files(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return render_template('home.html', **locals())

@views.route('/delete-note', methods=['POST'])
def delete_note():
    note = json.loads(request.data)
    noteId = note['noteId']
    note = Note.query.get(noteId)
    if note:
        if note.user_id == current_user.id:
            db.session.delete(note)
            db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({})

# ---

@views.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', user=None)

# ---

@views.route('/upload', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploadfile():
    upload_folder = current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
    if request.method == 'POST': # check if the method is post
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file'] # get the file from the files object
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file.save(os.path.join(
            upload_folder ,
            secure_filename(file.filename))) # this will secure the file

        flash('file uploaded successfully') # Display this message after uploading
    return redirect('/')

def get_files(target):
    for file in os.listdir(target):
        path = os.path.join(target, file)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            yield (
                file,
                datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path)),
                os.path.getsize(path)
            )

@views.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
        filename,
        as_attachment=True
    )
```

###### (templates/base.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>

    {{ moment.include_moment() }}

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbar"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a>
          {% else %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Login</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="Über Uns" href="/about">Über uns</a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} {% if
    messages %} {% for category, message in messages %} {% if category ==
    'error' %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
      {{ message }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-success alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
      {{ message }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %}



    <div class="container">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>


    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

###### (templates/home.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" -%}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock -%}
{% block content -%}

<h1 align="center">Notes</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
  {% for note in user.notes %}
  <li class="list-group-item">
    {{ note.data }}
    <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote({{ note.id }})">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<form method="POST">
  <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <br />
  <div align="center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>
  </div>
</form>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- upload Folder-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <h1 align="center">Datei Upload</h1>
      <hr>
        <form
          action="http://localhost:5000/upload"
          method="POST"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <input type="file" name="file" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- download Folder-->
<div align="center">
<image src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/postgre.jpeg')}}">
</div>

    <table style="width:40%; margin:auto; table-layout: fixed;">
      {% for filename, mtime, size in files -%}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ url_for('views.download', filename=filename) }}" download>{{ filename }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ moment(mtime, local=False).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm') }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">{{ size | byte_units }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor -%}
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (() => {
        const elems = document.querySelectorAll('a[href][download]');
        elems.forEach(elem => {
          elem.addEventListener('click', evt => {
            const isDonwload = window.confirm('Would you like to download this file?');
            if (!isDonwload) { evt.preventDefault(); }
          });
        });
      })();
    </script>
{% endblock -%}
```

Comment: Thank you very very muchI I will try it out on friday. If I can somehow show my gratitude, then let me know.

Comment: I hope your expectations will be met on Friday. I would be happy if you click on the tick.

Comment: @ detlef: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'byte_units'  

SOmehow my py makes probsand i dont know why?

Comment: It seems to me that you forgot the following line. This adds the function `byte_units` to the jinja environment as a filter. `app.jinja_env.filters.update(byte_units = byte_units)`.

Comment: @ detlef: Views.py and auth.py @auth.route('/') def index(): files = get_files(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']) return render_template('home.html', **locals()) It is something with rendering the page problem. DO you have for this any good solution? I dont know what could be wrong. I have already insert in auth.py the app.jinja_env.filters.update(byte_units = byte_units)

Comment: @Olej I've adjusted my answer even though I gave you a working, minimal example earlier. I see you are trying and I hope I was able to support you in getting a little closer to your goals.

Comment: @ detlef ur views. py --> return render_template('home.html', **locals()) making again problems and home.html -->jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'byte_units'

Comment: @Olej Did you take the code from `__init__.py`? There the filter is added globally.

Comment: @ detlef I will post everything again. But with your help, it worked out. I can send you a schnapsbottle :-D

Comment: @ detlef: I was continuing on this project and changed a lot. Now i face this problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71967842/how-to-create-a-tooltip-and-display-description-of-a-file-by-hovering-a-table-l

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @ Detlef a local webserver was created, which allows you to log in, sign up and leave notes. Then there were an upload and a download option set up.

I begin with the tree structure.

```
C:.
|   main.py
|   output.doc
|   
+---instance
|   |   database.db
|   |   
|   \---uploads
|           postgre.jpeg
|           project.jpg
|           
+---website
|   |   auth.py
|   |   database.db
|   |   models.py
|   |   output.doc
|   |   views.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---static
|   |   |   index.js
|   |   |   
|   |   \---Bilder
|   |           sun.jpg
|   |           logo.png
|   |           postgre.jpeg
|   |           
|   +---templates
|   |       about.html
|   |       base.html
|   |       home.html
|   |       login.html
|   |       sign_up.html
|   |       
|   \---__pycache__
|           app.cpython-39.pyc
|           auth.cpython-39.pyc
|           download.cpython-39.pyc
|           models.cpython-39.pyc
|           views.cpython-39.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
|
```

Starting with the main.py:

```
from website import create_app # website folder

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the auth.py:

```
from . import db
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from .models import User
from flask import (
    Blueprint,
    flash,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    url_for
)
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                flash('Logged in successfully!', category='success')
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect password, try again.', category='error')
        else:
            flash('Email does not exist.', category='error')

    return render_template('login.html', user=current_user)

@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        first_name = request.form.get('firstName')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            flash('Email already exists.', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email must be greater than 3 characters.', category='error')
        elif len(first_name) < 2:
            flash('First name must be greater than 1 character.', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords don\'t match.', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 7:
            flash('Password must be at least 7 characters.', category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(
                password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(new_user, remember=True)
            flash('Account created!', category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template('sign_up.html', user=current_user)
```

This is the views.py:

```
from . import db
from .models import Note
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, abort, jsonify
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from datetime import datetime
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import json
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask import Flask

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(app.instance_path, '/uploads')

moment = Moment(app)

@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note = request.form.get('note')

        if len(note) < 1:
            flash('Note is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            new_note = Note(data=note, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_note)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Note added!', category='success')

    user=current_user
    files = get_files(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return render_template('home.html', **locals())

@views.route('/delete-note', methods=['POST'])
def delete_note():
    note = json.loads(request.data)
    noteId = note['noteId']
    note = Note.query.get(noteId)
    if note:
        if note.user_id == current_user.id:
            db.session.delete(note)
            db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({})

# ---

@views.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', user=None)

# ---

@views.route('/upload', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploadfile():
    upload_folder = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
    if request.method == 'POST': # check if the method is post
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file'] # get the file from the files object
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file.save(os.path.join(
            upload_folder ,
            secure_filename(file.filename))) # this will secure the file

        flash('file uploaded successfully') # Display this message after uploading
    return redirect('/')

def get_files(target):
    for file in os.listdir(target):
        path = os.path.join(target, file)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            yield (
                file,
                datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path)),
                os.path.getsize(path)
            )

@views.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
        filename,
        as_attachment=True
    )
```

This is the **init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

DB_NAME = "database.db"

db = SQLAlchemy()
moment = Moment()

def byte_units(value, units=-1):
    UNITS=('Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB')
    i=1
    value /= 1000.0
    while value > 1000 and (units == -1 or i < units) and i+1 < len(UNITS):
        value /= 1000.0
        i += 1
    return f'{round(value,3):.3f} {UNITS[i]}'

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY=b'your secret here',
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///'+os.path.join(app.instance_path, DB_NAME),
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,
        UPLOAD_FOLDER=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads')
    )
    app.jinja_env.filters.update(byte_units = byte_units)

    try:
        os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    except:
        pass

    db.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)

    from .models import User, Note

    create_database(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')

    return app


def create_database(app):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(app.instance_path, DB_NAME)):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Created Database!')
```

This is the models.py:

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

THis is the home.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" -%}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock -%}
{% block content -%}

<h1 align="center">Notes</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
  {% for note in user.notes %}
  <li class="list-group-item">
    {{ note.data }}
    <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote({{ note.id }})">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<form method="POST">
  <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <br />
  <div align="center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>
  </div>
</form>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- upload Folder-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <h1 align="center">Datei Upload</h1>
      <hr>
        <form
          action="http://localhost:5000/upload"
          method="POST"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <input type="file" name="file" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- download Folder-->
<div align="center">
<image src="{{ url_for('static', filename='Bilder/postgre.jpeg')}}">
</div>

<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Downloads</h1>

    <table style="width:100%; margin:auto; table-layout: fixed;">
      {% for filename, mtime, size in files -%}
      <tr>
        <th>Dateiname</th>
        <th>Datum und Uhrzeit</th>
        <th>Dateigröße</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ url_for('views.download', filename=filename) }}" download>{{ filename }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ moment(mtime, local=False).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm') }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">{{ size | byte_units }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor -%}
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (() => {
        const elems = document.querySelectorAll('a[href][download]');
        elems.forEach(elem => {
          elem.addEventListener('click', evt => {
            const isDonwload = window.confirm('Möchten Sie die ausgewählte Datei herunterladen??');
            if (!isDonwload) { evt.preventDefault(); }
          });
        });
      })();
    </script>
{% endblock -%}
```

This is the login.hmtl

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Login{% endblock %} {% block content
%}
<form method="POST">
  <h3 align="center">Login</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email Addresse</label>
    <input
      type="email"
      class="form-control"
      id="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Email Eingabe"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Passwort</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      id="password"
      name="password"
      placeholder="Passwort Eingabe"
    />
  </div>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the sign_up.hmtl

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %} {% block
content %}
<body>
<h3 align="center"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='Bilder/Logo-NRL-blau.png') }}" alt=""></h3>
</body>

<form method="POST">
  <h3 align="center">Sign Up</h3>  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email-Addresse</label>
    <input
      type="email"
      class="form-control"
      id="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Email Eingabe"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">Vollständiger Name</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      id="firstName"
      name="firstName"
      placeholder="Eingabe des vollständigen Namens"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password1">Passwort</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      id="password1"
      name="password1"
      placeholder="Passwort Eingabe"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password2">Passwort (Wiederholung)</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      id="password2"
      name="password2"
      placeholder="Passwort (Bestätigung)"
    />
  </div>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the base.hmtl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>

    {{ moment.include_moment() }}

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbar"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a>
          {% else %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Login</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="Über Uns" href="/about">Über uns</a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} {% if
    messages %} {% for category, message in messages %} {% if category ==
    'error' %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
      {{ message }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-success alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
      {{ message }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %}



    <div class="container">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>


    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Have fun with it. AND THANKS to @ Detlef !!!!!!!