# Flask/Jinja2 - Iterating over nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, nested, jinja2

I'm trying to display the contents and structure of a dictionary in the form of a bunch of nested un-ordered lists.

The data that I've managed to pull together looks like this,

```
{'.': {'walk.py': None, 'what.html': None, 'misc': {}, 'orders': {'order1.html':  None, 'more': {'stuff.html': None}}}}
```

which represents this directory tree,

```
.:
misc/  orders/  walk.py  what.html

./misc:

./orders:
more/  order1.html

./orders/more:
stuff.html
```

How would I go about iterating over this using the Jinja2 Syntax? Is there a better way go about doing this?

Thanks in advace.

EDIT: I feel stupid. After searching for a solution again I discovered exactly what I was looking for. Guess my google-fu wasn't really with me the first try. 
[Here it is...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961378/how-to-generate-an-html-directory-list-using-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using the `recursive` modifier of the [`for` loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for) (example taken from the docs):

```
<ul class="sitemap">
{%- for item in sitemap recursive %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.href|e }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {%- if item.children -%}
        <ul class="submenu">{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
    {%- endif %}</li>
{%- endfor %}
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is something I came up with:

```
from jinja2 import Template

x = Template("""{%- for key, value in tree.iteritems() recursive %}
{{ '--' * (loop.depth-1) }}{{ key }}
{%- if value is mapping -%}/{{ loop(value.iteritems()) }}{%- endif -%}
{%- endfor %}
""")

tree = {'.': {
    'walk.py': None,
    'what.html': None,
    'misc': {},
    'orders': {
        'order1.html': None,
        'more': {
            'stuff.html': None
        }
    }
}}

print x.render(tree=tree)
```

Output:

```
./
--walk.py
--what.html
--misc/
--orders/
----order1.html
----more/
------stuff.html
```

(The dashes in the Jinja2 code (e.g. `{%- ... -%}` are for [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#whitespace-control). Play around with that.)

Comment: if it worked, you should accept the answer for others to learn from

Answer (score 1):

Why not just a nested for loop?

in your views.py:

```
def index(request):
    context={'main1':{'sub1','sub2','sub3'},'main2':{'sub1','sub2'}}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

in your index.html:

```
{% for key1,val in context.items %}
    <p> {{ key1 }} </p>
    <ul>
    {% for key2 in val.items %}
            <li> {{key2}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It is possible to simply use a nested for loop if you know the exact depth of the tree. But then you probably have more to write and a more general solution without knowing the exact depth of the incoming data is really good to have.

Answer (score 0):

First organize the data:

```
a = {'.': {'walk.py': None, 'what.html': None, 'misc': {}, 'orders': {'order1.html':  None, 'more': {'stuff.html': None}}}}    

from collections import defaultdict

def f(data, path):
    for k,v in data.iteritems():
        if v is None:
            yield path,k
        else:
            yield path,k+"/"
            for k in f(v,path+k+"/"):
                yield k

def process_data():
    collect = defaultdict(list)
    for p in f(a,""):
        if p[0]:
            collect[p[0][:-1]].append(p[1])
    return collect
```

Now if you run:

```
data = process_data()
for k in data.keys():
    print k,data[k]
```

You get:

```
./orders ['order1.html', 'more/']
./orders/more ['stuff.html']
. ['walk.py', 'what.html', 'misc/', 'orders/']
```

Thats all you need for rendering. The template should be something like:

```
{% for k in sitemap.keys()|sort -%}
    {{ k }}:<br/>
    {% for v in sitemap[k] %}
    {{ v }}
    {%- endfor %}
    <br/>
{%- endfor %}
```

and the call for rendering:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('temp.html',sitemap=process_data())
```

Which in my test renders as:

```
.:<br/>    
walk.py
what.html
misc/
orders/
<br/>./orders:<br/>    
order1.html
more/
<br/>./orders/more:<br/>    
stuff.html
<br/>
```