# Generating a recursive sitemap with relative href links

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using Flask to expose a local directory of HTML files on a web page.

I am also using a `jinja2` to generate the sitemap in the lefthand `div` of my main endpoint.

I am **unable** to correctly specify the URL to the endpoint of my subfolders.

As mentioned in the code below, how would I dynamically build a relative link from `/docs` (i.e. `/docs/folder1/subfolder1/SubFolder1Page.html`)?
The way I am currently setting the value for `href` obviously does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Docs Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="left_frame">
            <h1>{{ tree.name }}</h1>
            <ul>
            {%- for item in tree.children recursive %}
                <!-- How would I build a relative link from /docs/ i.e. /docs/folder1/subfolder1/SubFolder1Page.html -->
                <li><a href="docs/{{ item.name }}" target="iframe1">{{ item.name }}
                {%- if item.children -%}
                    <ul>{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
                {%- endif %}</a></li>
            {%- endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right_frame">
            <iframe name="iframe1"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Folder structure example:

[image: demo structure]

How it looks overall displaying the contents of `file1.html`:
[image: sitemap view]

Comment: Have you tried building your tree containing all the path names like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961378/how-to-generate-an-html-directory-list-using-python ?

Comment: @jbndlr That's exactly the post I looked at initially. And that's where I ended up. Fortunately, I found the solution to the problem I was having myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured out a satisfying way of solving my own issue.

I managed to get this very functional result:
[image: Flask serving Docs demo]

Do note that my template is only good for files with `.html` extension, though it can be easily enhanced to support other file extensions.

Here is my finalized `templates\template.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Docs Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="left_frame">
            <h1>{{ tree.name }}</h1>
            <ul>
            {%- for item in tree.children recursive %}
                {% if '.html' in item.name %}
                    <li><a href="docs/{{ item.name }}" target="iframe1">
                    {{ item.name.split('/')[-1:][0] }}
                    {%- if item.children -%}
                        <ul>{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
                    {%- endif %}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li>{{ item.name }}
                    {%- if item.children -%}
                        <ul>{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
                    {%- endif %}</li>
                {% endif %}
            {%- endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right_frame">
            <iframe name="iframe1"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can refer to **King Reload**'s answer for an analysis of what I've changed in the `template.html` file to make this work correctly.

And here is the `demo_app.py` script that serves my document HTML files via Flask:

```
import threading
import os
import webbrowser
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DOCS_ROOT = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'docs')


@app.route('/')
def docs_tree():
    return render_template('template.html', tree=make_tree(DOCS_ROOT))


@app.route('/docs/<path:filename>')
def send_docs(filename):
    return send_from_directory(directory=DOCS_ROOT, 'docs'), filename=filename)


def make_tree(path):
    tree = dict(name=os.path.basename(path), children=[])
    try:
        lst = os.listdir(path)
    except OSError:
        pass  # ignore errors
    else:
        for name in lst:
            fn = os.path.join(path, name)
            if os.path.isdir(fn):
                tree['children'].append(make_tree(fn))
            else:
                np = os.path.join(path.replace(DOCS_ROOT, ''), name).replace('\\', '/')
                if np.startswith('/'):
                    np = np[1:]
                tree['children'].append(dict(name=np))
    return tree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = 'localhost'
    port = '8888'
    url = 'http://{h}:{p}'.format(h=host, p=port)
    threading.Timer(3, lambda: webbrowser.open(url)).start()
    app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=False)
```

Most notable changes in `demo_app.py` since asking my original question were the following:

- After initializing `app`, I set `DOCS_ROOT` using `app.static_folder`;
- In the function `send_docs()`, I changed the `send_from_directory()`'s `directory` argument to use `DOCS_ROOT`;
- Inside of `make_tree()`, inside the `else` block of the `for` loop, I added:

  ```
  np = os.path.join(path.replace(DOCS_ROOT, ''), name).replace('\\', '/')
  if np.startswith('/'):
      np = np[1:]
  ```

  All this does is take the absolute path of `name`, remove what matches `DOCS_ROOT`, leaving only the relative path (and then replacing the `\\` for `/`), resulting in a simple relative path from `static/docs`. If the relative path starts with a `/`, I remove it (since there is a trailing `/` from `docs` in `template.html`.

---

For anyone interested in the simplistic stylesheet (`static\styles.css`) I used (along with some updated enhancements):

```
html {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.left_frame {
    float:left;
    background:#E8F1F5;
    width:25%;
    height:100vh;
}

.right_frame {
    float:right;
    background:#FAFAFA;
    width:75%;
    height:100vh;
}

.right_frame iframe {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add onto the solution of @HEADLESS_0NE:

He added a few more `if` statements in the `for loop`, like so:

```
       {%- for item in tree.children recursive %}
    ->        {% if '.html' in item.name %}
                <li><a href="docs/{{ item.name }}" target="iframe1">
    ->            {{ item.name.split('/')[-1:][0] }}
                {%- if item.children -%}
                    <ul>{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
                {%- endif %}</a></li>
    ->        {% else %}
    ->            <li>{{ item.name }}
    ->            {%- if item.children -%}
    ->                <ul>{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
    ->            {%- endif %}</li>
    ->        {% endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
```

Everything with an `->` has been changed in the `html`, I couldn't find what he added in his `python` or `css`, but in short:

- An `if` to check if there's a `.html` in the `item.name`.
- A split on the `item.name`, so the `/` gets removed.
- An `else` statement if there's no `.html` in the `item.name`.

This basically adds the `ul`'s and the `li`'s in the correct format.

For a more detailed explanation I hope HEADLESS_0NE could provide us of more information what he might've changed in the `python` script.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to further explain my changes to the Jinja template file. My example file wasn't versioned, so I'll do my best.

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE no problem :) I tried my best to explain it in further detail! Thanks for the updates to your post and explenation how you solved it ;)

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE thanks for explaining the `python` in more detail :) I appreciate it ^^ already gave +1 on question and answer :) hope it may help a lot of users with the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

With flask, I have built a site map using the following

```
from flask import url_for

def get_flask_resources():
    verbs = ["POST","GET","PUT","DELETE"]

    resources = {}
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if has_no_empty_params(rule):
            resource = url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            if resource not in resources:
                resources[resource] = {}
            for verb in verbs:
                if verb in rule.methods:
                    resources[resource][verb] = {
                        'function':rule.endpoint,
                        'docs':app.view_functions[rule.endpoint].__doc__
                    }
        else:
            resource = rule.rule
            if resource not in resources:
                resources[resource] = {}
            for verb in verbs:
                if verb in rule.methods:
                    resources[resource][verb] = {
                        'function':rule.endpoint,
                        'docs':app.view_functions[rule.endpoint].__doc__
                    }

    return resources
```

This function returns a dictionary like this

```
{
  "/endpoint1": {
    "GET": {
      "docs": "", 
      "function": "endpoint1"
    }
  }, 
  "/endpoint2": {
    "GET": {
      "docs": "", 
      "function": "endpoint2"
    }
  }, 
  "/endpoint1/something": {
    "POST": {
      "docs": "", 
      "function": "endpoint1_something"
    }
  }, 
}
```

I had an endpoint return this data and then formatted it on the front end. The dictionary keys are the URIs that you would want to use in the links.

This does assume that you will have a flask route set up for each HTML document, which may not be the case.

One benefit of using this would be that it is dynamic if you add any more HTML documents/Flask routes.

Comment: That's great, but, as you've suspected, it's not what I'm looking for. Thanks for sharing though!